# How to use the new android 4.4 emulator?

Tags: android

It seens to be stuck on the final part of the tutorial, where it asks me to say a command. It wont display the home screen with the usual shortcuts, like the available apps. It just shows the clock and a card with the final instruction.
Also, it wont ask me to unlock the screen and I cant figure how to add shortcuts on the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try alternative emulator for `Android` - [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). It works faster then native `Android` emulator.

Comment: I don't really like it how it is dependant on an account, but google messed up and It worked fine on ubuntu.

Comment: it's a good alternative for native emulator, which is too slow sometimes

Comment: I agree, but it is pretty fast on ubuntu, I didnt had any issues until the update. On the other hand I couldn't make genymotion run on windows when I tried a few months ago. On the other hand the regular emulator wouldnt work on mac after a given update. I really dont like emulators.